# Visual Studio 2012 Error: Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "WordClientPkgLib"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, error-handling

I have received following error while trying to do replace a style set in word document. This will replace the styles in multiple document, currently i am building in visual studio 2012. kindly help me on this.

Error:
Warning 1   Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "WordClientPkgLib". Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)) doc replacing

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim word_app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
            Dim word_doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

            word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            word_app.Visible = True

            Dim path As String = Me.TextBox1.Text

            Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(path)

            Dim comnothing As Object
            comnothing = New Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper(Nothing)
            word_app = comnothing
            word_doc = comnothing
            For Each f As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("*.docx")
                word_doc = word_app.Documents.Open(path & "\" & f.Name)
                word_doc.ApplyQuickStyleSet("Transcript_v4")
                word_app.Selection.WholeStory()
                word_app.Selection.Style = word_doc.Styles("Normal Continuing")
                word_app.Selection.HomeKey()
                word_app.Selection.Style = word_doc.Styles("Normal Initial")
                word_doc.Save()
                word_doc.Close()

                'MsgBox(f.Name)                        
            Next f

            MsgBox("Completed processing the files...")
            word_app.Quit()
        End Sub
```

Comment: This is weird. VS complains about WordClientPkgLib, but the code you are providing (because you are clearly providing all the code) doesn't include any reference to WordClientPkgLib! Perhaps your VS is broken; or VB is wrong. Have you tried to restart the computer?. PS (I clarify because am not sure that everyone will get the joke): I am joking, please, provide all the code related to the error you are complaining about.

Comment: The program run's properly and results also good, but the debugger show this error which i don't know why. i have tested the above code in separate forms but still it show the error.

Comment: I repeat (last time) the underlying idea to my sarcastic comment above: you cannot complain about something which happens ONLY in your code without showing the given part and expecting other people to know what is going wrong (well... it is clear: you are referring to an external resource which is not included in your project; the question is: why the code you have, about which your knowledge seems quite limited, is doing such a thing?). Additionally, if the program can run, it is not called error, but warning. Please, try to not waste others' time in a so useless way.